# Hot Spot Analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, heat-map, hot-spot

I'm using ArcMap 10.2- I've got a series of coordinate points, each with an associated value (level of income) that I would like to turn into a heatmap.

I've projected the points onto a map, run the optimized hot spot tool, and it has changed the color of each of the points based on the Z scores from deep red to deep blue.  However I want to go from colored dots to a fully shaded map, particularly like the second and third maps under "Example 1" here:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/analysis/017z00000015000000.htm

Comment: Theres a few ways to interpolate a surface. You could run Natural Neighbor on the points (and run Reclassify on that output if you need). Theres a few other ways to create a surface. Note though, generally your data lends itself towards one method over another.

Comment: This GPK you can download demonstrates the entire workflow I mentioned above : http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=02b7dddf672f40c4b0129aa7420105d9

Comment: Your examples are considered more of a heat map than a hot spot map. (Yes, I know you can argue about the definition of a heat map, but at least colloquially, that's what the examples are). Arc has a kernel density tool as one option, in, I think, the spatial analyst extension that can create these maps.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @KHibma:

> There's a few ways to interpolate a surface. You could run Natural
> Neighbor on the points (and run Reclassify on that output if you
> need). Theres a few other ways to create a surface. Note though,
> generally your data lends itself towards one method over another.

and

> This [Geoprocessing Package for 911 Call HotSpots] you can download demonstrates the entire
> workflow I mentioned above :
> http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=02b7dddf672f40c4b0129aa7420105d9
>
> This geoprocessing package creates a hotspot surface based on 911 call
> locations. This service was demonstrated at the Esri DevSummit 2012 in
> the Geoprocessing Service Sessions